# Node.js relocate hash elements according to value order

Tags: node.js, sorting

I wonder whether it's possible to change the order of hash elements based on the orders for values.

for example,

```
a = { a:3, b:1, c:2}
a = sort_on_values(a)
a = { b:1, c:2, a:3}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that properties on an objects are a *set*, meaning they have no order, so trying to sort them is not worthwhile.

The particular implementation (node.js) may happen to always return them in insertion order, in which case you are lucky, but I would not rely on that.

If you want an ordered list, then use an ordered list like an array.

For example:

```
var array = [ { a: 3 }, { b: 1 }, { c: 2 } ];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[Object.keys(a)[0]] - b[Object.keys(b)[0]];
});

console.log(array);
```

prints out something like

```
[
  { b: 1 },
  { c: 2 },
  { a: 3 }
]
```